# Tor Unexpectedly Exited. This might be due to a bug in Tor itself, another program... MAC OSX Sierra

Tags: configuration, error, mac, tor-install, troubleshooting

Seen many posts on this with no working solution. Installed Tor via website for Mac OS Sierra. Can't see any other Tor process running in Activity Monitor. Inside my torbrowser.app I double clicked the "tor" file and this is what it said (if it's of any use):

```
/Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/Resources/TorBrowser/Tor/tor ; exit;
Nov 02 01:33:11.580 [notice] Tor 0.3.1.7 (git-6babd3d9ba9318b3) running on Darwin with Libevent 2.0.22-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.2k, Zlib 1.2.8, Liblzma N/A, and Libzstd N/A.
Nov 02 01:33:11.581 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Nov 02 01:33:11.654 [notice] Configuration file "/home/debian/install/etc/tor/torrc" not present, using reasonable defaults.
Nov 02 01:33:11.658 [warn] Couldn't set maximum number of file descriptors: Invalid argument
Nov 02 01:33:11.658 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Problem with ConnLimit value. See logs for details.
Nov 02 01:33:11.658 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
Deleting expired sessions...none found.
```

Also inside the package in the same folder is torrc-defaults but no torrc on its own. Either way can't open browser despite months of trying, deleting the file etc. Somebody suggested something else could be using Port 80 - is that a valid reason? If so how do I fix it or determine the problem?!

Comment: I think this is related to [#21074](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/21074). nickm said if it was observed in >=0.3.1.7 then re-open the ticket, so I guess we should.

Comment: OK I took a look at that thread, I don't understand what it means by use ULIMIT_BUFFER for open files? However, I tried typing this into Terminal from a comment in #21074:

sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 10000 10000


This seemed to fix the problem as I finally can launch the Tor browser, I'm not sure if it's permanent or if there was a better fix submitted. P.S. Can somebody explain what the above code does as I'm not a coder? Thank you

Comment: Basically, it allows applications to open a larger number of "files" at once (by files it means, opening files on disk, or internet connections). Tor Browser tries to increase the limit, to stop it from causing problems, but something goes wrong with it and Tor considers this a failure and quits. Running the `launchctl` command manually raises the limit, so Tor Browser doesn't have to bother trying to. I've notified the developers that you're still having that issue, so hopefully a better long-term fix can be made and will be deployed in a later Tor Browser update.

Comment: After last security update OS X el Capitan 10.11.6 - tor stopped working
"*Tor Unexpectedly Exited. This might be due to a bug in Tor itself, another program..*".
I used this command in terminal
**`sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 10000 10000`**
It works! Tor is opening now! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You launch the browser like any other app on the Mac: by double-clicking the app bundle's icon. The files inside may not work correctly if invoked on their own, and are generally not intended to be used that way.